# Sessão PHP expirando rápido

Tags: php

As sessões do meu PHP estão expirando em um curto tempo(5min), mesmo utilizando session_cache_expire(120), e precisaria que fosse pelo menos 2horas.

Estou usando um código parecido com esse:

```
session_cache_expire(120);
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){ 
    header("Location: ../../index.html");
}else{
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
}
```

No phpinfo() tenho as seguintes informações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quanto tempo você queria que a sessão durasse?

Comment: Defina rápido (curto tempo)? Tem evidências? Como podemos saber o que de fato está ocorrendo? Não me lembro bem mais se pode mudar em tempo de execução em qualquer situação, se está em hospedagem compartilhada é provável que não possa. Mas deveria permitir bem mais tempo.

Comment: @Bacco, esta expirando em menos de 5min. Gostaria que ficasse umas 2horas.

Comment: e como você comprovou que o problema é a sessão?

Comment: Pelo código acima. imagino que o "if(!isset($SESSION['id']){}" sirva exatamente para isso: para quando não existir mais a variável da sessão(id) ela se redirecione para o arquivo de caminho ../../index.html

Comment: Acesse sua aplicação com as ferramentas do desenvolvedor aberta, vá em Application, Storage, Cookies, acesse o seu domínio, busque pelo cookie PHPSESSID e verifique o valor em Expires / Max-Age.

Comment: O valor é esse: 1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z, @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: E o que você conclui com isso?

Comment: Alterar o tempo de vida da sessão...  pelo que pesquisei aqui, posso utilizar o seguinte comando: ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 120*60);

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, correto?

Comment: Será que não existe algum .htaccess com configurações de sessão? Tive um caso assim, estava definido nesse arquivo e configurações nos arquivos php não surtiam efeito.